# Using .reduce on an object containing array elements to convert it to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I'm trying to convert an object which contains arrays as its property, to an array which contains all elements from these nested arrays.

Here's what i am trying to do:

```js
data1 = [{
  a: 1,
  b: ["uz", "vy"]
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: ["wxa", "xwy"]
}, {
  a: 6,
  b: ["ysa", "zaa"]
}]

data1.reduce(function(q, w) {
  return q.b.concat(w.b)
})
```

I want the final data to look like this:

```
data1 = ["uz","vy","wxa","xwy","ysa","zaa"]
```

However this gives an error message :

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'concat' of undefined"
```

If `q.b` refers to array inside object, why does it not have `concat` property?
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: `reduce` needs an aggregator, here, you should use an empty array (`[]`)

Comment: supply an initial value to `reduce` - `[]`. Also should be `q.concat`.

Comment: You could use `console.log([].concat(...data.map(({b}) => b)))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an error because `q` is an array and not an object with `b` property. And you did not add the initial value.

You can `concat` and `map`

```js
let data1 = [{a: 1,b: ["uz", "vy"]}, {a: 2,b: ["wxa", "xwy"]}, {a: 6,b: ["ysa", "zaa"]}];

let result = [].concat(...data1.map(o => o.b));

console.log(result);
```

---

If you want to use `reduce`, you can:

```js
let data1 = [{a: 1,b: ["uz", "vy"]}, {a: 2,b: ["wxa", "xwy"]}, {a: 6,b: ["ysa", "zaa"]}];

let result = data1.reduce(function(q, w) {
  return q.concat(w.b);
}, []); //<-- Add [] to initiate the initial value

console.log(result);
```

Comment: But if i do this : **data1.reduce(function(q,w){ console.log(q) })**. I get an object as output. Shouldn't this mean 'q' is being passed as object initially ?

Comment: @VSharma That is because you did not initiate the initial value, which should be an array. If you won't, the first element will be the initial value.

Comment: You need to put the initial value as an array because you expected output is an array.

Comment: If I don't pass in the initial value, the first element 'q' will be an object. Thus 'q.b' will be an array. Shouldn't 'concat' be a method on this array?

Comment: Yes, that will only be on the first loop. `concat` returns an array, so on the second loop, `q` is now an array. and that is where you are getting the error. @VSharma

Comment: Sorry but i still don't understand. If 'q' is an array on second loop, why would 'concat' not be a function on 'q' ? It shows error q.concat is not a function.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170865/discussion-between-v-sharma-and-eddie).

Answer (score 2):

Pass an initial value to the `reduce` function. Also, `q.b` will not be a valid value in the first call. You wanted to concat to `q` instead:

```js
data1 = [{
  a: 1,
  b: ["uz", "vy"]
}, {
  a: 2,
  b: ["wxa", "xwy"]
}, {
  a: 6,
  b: ["ysa", "zaa"]
}]

var result = data1.reduce(function(q, w) {
  return q.concat(w.b);
}, [])

console.log(result);
```